# How can I import a react application cloned from github in my local to my existing react project when the dependencies are different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm

In my ejected CRA I want to import a local react application which consists of dependencies different than my working application dependencies . How can I import that react application in my local to the working react application.
Working application dependency :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "ant-design-draggable-modal": "0.0.13",
    "antd": "^3.23.5",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "bizcharts": "^3.5.5",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connected-react-router": "4.3.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    }
```

Dependencies of file need to be imported.

```
"dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.9.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.6 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.4.1 ",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^0.14.6 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.4.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6 || ^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
    }
```